# Combine 3 streams with Observables in series and in parallel

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I am trying to combine 3 HTTP requests into 1 response.

The last 2 requests depend on data from the first request. I chose the following approach using `flatMap` and `forkJoin` after reading [this post](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/).

The author is using an older version of Angular and RXjs so I have modified it to use piped operators. But I am still unable to get the response I need.

```
  public getAllData(params): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.base}/seasons.json`, {params: params})
    .pipe(
      map((data: SeasonBase) => data.MRData.SeasonTable.Seasons),
      flatMap((seasons: Season[]) => {
        if(seasons.length > 0) {
          return forkJoin(
            of(seasons),
            seasons.map((season: Season) => {
              return this.http.get(`${this.base}/${season.season}/results/1.json`)
                .pipe(
                  map((data: RaceBase) => data.MRData.RaceTable)
                )
            }),
            seasons.map((season: Season) => {
              return this.http.get(`${this.base}/${season.season}/driverStandings.json`)
                .pipe(
                  map((d: any) => d.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0])
                )
            })
          ).pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
              let season = data[0];
              let races = data[1];
              let standings = data[2];
              season.testRaces = races;
              season.standings = standings;
              return season;
            })
          )
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

The above method return the following response when subscribing:

[image]

The response I am trying to get should be more like this:

```
{
  season: "1950", 
  url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Formula_One_season",
  testRaces: [test_races_data], // dont want observable
  standings: [standings_data] // dont want observable
},
{...},
{...}
etc
```

`testRaces` and `standings` are being returned as Observables instead of responses.

Is it possible to "unwrap" the 2 Obseravbles before returning the response so that I can map the data?

[**Here is a stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enkltf) of the code as it is currently written. You can check the dev tools console to see the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class ErgastService, lines 24 and 30 are returning an array of observables instead of their content.

The quick solution is to add two forkJoin as I do in this forked version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l3wkmw?file=src/app/api.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
seasons.map((season: Season) => {
          return this.http.get(`${this.base}/${season.season}/results/1.json`)
```

Creates an observable of observables. Use `flatMap` instead of `map`, then you get an observable that emits the value.